# Expected input batch_size (18) to match target batch_size (6)

Tags: pytorch, classification, recurrent-neural-network, image-classification

Is RNN for image classification available only for gray image?
The following program works for gray image classification.

If RGB images are used, I have this error:

> Expected input batch_size (18) to match target batch_size (6)

at this line `loss = criterion(outputs, labels)`.

My data loading for train, valid and test are as follows.

```
input_size  = 300
inputH = 300
inputW = 300

#Data transform (normalization & data augmentation)
stats = ((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010))
train_resize_tfms = tt.Compose([tt.Resize((inputH, inputW), interpolation=2),
                         tt.ToTensor(),
                         tt.Normalize(*stats)])

train_tfms = tt.Compose([tt.Resize((inputH, inputW), interpolation=2),
                         tt.RandomHorizontalFlip(),                                                  
                         tt.ToTensor(),
                         tt.Normalize(*stats)])
valid_tfms = tt.Compose([tt.Resize((inputH, inputW), interpolation=2),
                         tt.ToTensor(), 
                         tt.Normalize(*stats)])
test_tfms = tt.Compose([tt.Resize((inputH, inputW), interpolation=2),
                        tt.ToTensor(), 
                        tt.Normalize(*stats)])

#Create dataset
train_ds = ImageFolder('./data/train', train_tfms)
valid_ds = ImageFolder('./data/valid', valid_tfms)
test_ds = ImageFolder('./data/test', test_tfms)

from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
batch_size = 6

#Training data loader
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle = True, num_workers = 8, pin_memory=True)
#Validation data loader
valid_dl = DataLoader(valid_ds, batch_size, shuffle = True, num_workers = 8, pin_memory=True)
#Test data loader
test_dl = DataLoader(test_ds, 1, shuffle = False, num_workers = 1, pin_memory=True)
```

My model is as follows.

```
num_steps = 300
hidden_size = 256 #size of hidden layers
num_classes = 5
num_epochs = 20
learning_rate = 0.001
# Fully connected neural network with one hidden layer
num_layers = 2 # 2 RNN layers are stacked  
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True, dropout=0.2)#batch must have first dimension
        #our inpyt needs to have shape
        #x -> (batch_size, seq, input_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)#this fc is after RNN. So needs the last hidden size of RNN

    def forward(self, x):
        #according to ducumentation of RNN in pytorch
        #rnn needs input, h_0 for inputs at RNN (h_0 is initial hidden state)

        #the following one is initial hidden layer
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)#first one is number of layers and second one is batch size
        #output has two outputs. The first tensor contains the output features of the hidden last layer for all time steps
        #the second one is hidden state f
        out, _ = self.rnn(x, h0)
        #output has batch_size, num_steps, hidden size
        #we need to decode hidden state only the last time step
        #out (N, 30, 128)
        #Since we need only the last time step
        #Out (N, 128)
        out = out[:, -1, :] #-1 for last time step, take all for N and 128
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out


stacked_rnn_model = RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes).to(device)

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()#cross entropy has softmax at output
#optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(stacked_rnn_model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate) #optimizer used gradient optimization using Adam 
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(stacked_rnn_model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
# Train the model
n_total_steps = len(train_dl)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        t_losses=[]
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_dl):  
            # origin shape: [6, 3, 300, 300]
            # resized: [6, 300, 300]
            images = images.reshape(-1, num_steps, input_size).to(device)
            print('images shape')
            print(images.shape)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            
            # Forward pass
            outputs = stacked_rnn_model(images)
            print('outputs shape')
            print(outputs.shape)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            t_losses.append(loss)
            # Backward and optimize
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
```

Printing images and outputs shapes are

```
images shape
torch.Size([18, 300, 300])
outputs shape
torch.Size([18, 5])
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: What is `input_size` worth, and where is `stacked_rnn_model` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tl;dr**: You are flattening the first two axes, namely `batch` and `channels`.

---

I am not sure you are taking the right approach but I will write about that layer.

In any case, let's look at the issue you are facing. You have a data loader that produces `(6, 3, 300, 300)`, i.e. batches of 6 *three-channel `300x300` images*. By the look of it you are looking to reshape each batch element `(3, 300, 300)` into `(step_size=300, -1)`.

However instead of that you are affecting the first axis - which you shouldn't - with `images.reshape(-1, num_steps, input_size)`. This will have the desired effect when working with a single-channel images since `dim=1` wouldn't be the "channel axis". In your case your have *3* channels, therefore, the resulting shape is: `(6*3*300*300//300//300, 300, 300)` which is `(18, 300, 300)` since `num_steps=300` and `input_size=300`. As a result you are left with *18* batch elements instead of *6*.

Instead what you want is to reshape with `(batch_size, num_steps, -1)`. Leaving the last axis (a.k.a. `seq_length`) of variable size. This will result in a shape `(6, 300, 900)`.

---

Here is a corrected and reduced snippet:

```
batch_size = 6
channels = 3
inputH, inputW = 300, 300
train_ds = TensorDataset(torch.rand(100, 3, inputH, inputW), torch.rand(100, 5))
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size)

class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        # (batch_size, seq, input_size)
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        # (batch_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
        # (batch_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out, _ = self.rnn(x)
        out = out[:, -1, :]
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

num_steps = 300
input_size = inputH*inputW*channels//num_steps
hidden_size = 256
num_classes = 5
num_layers = 2

rnn = RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes)
for x, y in train_dl:
    print(x.shape, y.shape)
    images = images.reshape(batch_size, num_steps, -1)
    print(images.shape)
    outputs = rnn(images)
    print(outputs.shape)
    break
```

---

As I said in the beginning I am a bit wary about this approach because you are essentially feeding your RNN a RGB `300x300` image in the form of a sequence of *300* flattened vectors... I can't say if that makes sense and terms of training and if the model will be able to learn from that. I could be wrong!

Comment: Is that make sense, if the image is gray scale?

Comment: Maybe it does, if you consider you are processing your image line by line as a sequence of `300` vectors of size `300`. I am not sure about RGB, you would have to look at where the channels blend in your sequence... if they are they sequential or not.  In the code above input size is `3*300` i.e. a three-channel pixel 'line', so that could actually work in the end... You need to try training and see if you can get results with it. I hope I could be of help!

Comment: Yes it does very much help, but why you consider 6*3*300*300//300//300 this in the first dimension. Could explain one more time?

Comment: Sure. In your code you called `reshape(-1, num_steps, input_size)` on a tensor of size `(6, 3, 300, 300)` (total length: `6*3*300*300`). The resulting tensor will have `num_steps` on `dim=1` (i.e. `300`) and `input_size` on `dim=2` (i.e. `300` as well). On `dim=0` you have `-1` which means "flatten all remaining components there". The size of the remaining component is `total_size / product([size_dim for each other dim])` (in pseudo code). Which corresponds to `6*3*300*300/(300*300)=18`. Therefore length is worth `18` on `dim=0`.

Comment: Yes that is why input size 900 doesn't make any sense. Now I got it thanks.